# how to find dependencies for building debian package?

Tags: git, dependencies, debian, packaging

I want to build a package from git repository, and I don't know how can I find it's dependencies.
I used this document, but still I don't know how can I find it's dependencies.
http://xenomai.org/2014/06/building-debian-packages/

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a prerequisite section which should be all the required dependencies.

```
# apt-get install devscripts debhelper dh-kpatches findutils
```

Also when you are building the package using the steps, it will throw errors if the dependencies aren't met at which point you can install the dependency and resume.